# webpush.sendNotification - NotificationEvent.notification.data null

Tags: node.js, push-notification, notifications, service-worker, web-push

## Setup

*Operating System*: Linux
*Node Version*: 10.15.3
*web-push Version*: 3.3.4

- [X] Chrome
- [ ] Firefox
- [ ] Opera for Android
- [ ] Samsung Internet Browser
- [ ] Other

*Chrome: Version* 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

## Problem

I am trying to implement example step 5.2 from [google pwa lab](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-integrating-web-push)

If I push a notification from my node/main.js script I am getting the visual notification on my screen. If I click the notification I can observe from the console the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'primaryKey' of null
    at sw.js:30
```

If I check the content of the NotificationEvent.notification.data object it is **null**.

## Expected

If I click the notification sent from my node server I should be able to see the data from the NotificationEvent.notification object.

## Features Used

- [x] VAPID Support
- [ ] GCM API Key
- [x] Sending with Payload

## Example / Reproduce Case

This is my node/main.js that is in charge of the web push notifications.

```
const webPush = require('web-push');

const pushSubscription = {
    endpoint: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/flcWNQgYeVw:APA91bHgAC5M-WeyN5RNdSprIDUalAxSMznny3-QwPf2T8whtWwmtZ6Q546Pry-JCZqjSh9bbEIS778lJD7Hq-t4KLS35X6-T7dJGCnc_ECzKvsdOAQ50wlzQ5Tcm1WNvgOOwXV',
    expirationTime: null,
    keys: {
        p256dh: 'BL-Rz9Nejsd7ipsYQsQ9YB6tUc-qldkBg28y7G9LBFGdKe52sSeF0FStiKmdBp5BRFf3HazlOICBAVnY',
        auth: 'hOPxUEqXsdfFjB-MmFxaTw'
    }
};

// TODO 4.3a - include VAPID keys
const vapidPublicKey = 'MY VAPID PUBLIC KEY';
const vapidPrivateKey = 'MY VAPID PRIVATE KEY';

const payload = 'Here is a payload!';

const options = {
  //gcmAPIKey: 'NOT IN USE',
  TTL: 60,
  vapidDetails: {
      subject: 'mailto: myemail@gmail.com',
      publicKey: vapidPublicKey,
      privateKey: vapidPrivateKey
    },
    contentEncoding: 'aes128gcm'
};

webPush.sendNotification(
  pushSubscription,
  payload,
  options
).catch( error => {
    console.log(error);
}) ;
```

This is the code from my service worker that handles the notifications:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclose', event => {
  console.log(event);

  const notification = event.notification;

  const primaryKey = notification.data.primaryKey;

  console.log('Closed notification: ' + primaryKey);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  const notification = event.notification;
  console.log(notification.data);

  const primaryKey = notification.data.primaryKey;
  const action = event.action;

  if (action === 'close') {
    notification.close();
  } else {
    event.waitUntil(
      clients.matchAll().then(clis => {
        const client = clis.find(c => {
          return c.visibilityState === 'visible';
        });
        if (client !== undefined) {
          client.navigate('samples/page' + primaryKey + '.html');
          client.focus();
        } else {
          // there are no visible windows. Open one.
          clients.openWindow('samples/page' + primaryKey + '.html');
          notification.close();
        }
      })
    );
  }

  self.registration.getNotifications().then(notifications => {
    notifications.forEach(notification => {
      notification.close();
    });
  });
});

self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  let body;

  if (event.data) {
    body = event.data.text();
  } else {
    body = 'Default body';
  }

  const options = {
    body: body,
    icon: 'images/notification-flat.png',
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: 1
    },
    actions: [
      {action: 'explore', title: 'Go to the site',
        icon: 'images/checkmark.png'},
      {action: 'close', title: 'Close the notification',
        icon: 'images/xmark.png'},
    ]
  };
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll().then(c => {
      console.log(c);
      if (c.length === 0) {
        // Show notification
        self.registration.showNotification('Push Notification', options);
      } else {
        // Send a message to the page to update the UI
        console.log('Application is already open!');
      }
    })
  );
});
```

## Other

I have tried changing the contentEncoding from aesgmc to aes128gcm but I am still getting the same error.

If I run the web-push command I see the same error